# Browser Check Redirect Safari

Tags: codeigniter, safari, user-agent

I have this code in codeigniter to redirect older browsers to the upgrade page. It works in every browser except Safari, where a user with version 5.1 can view the site. Any ideas what is different with this one?

Thanks

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');

if (($this->agent->browser() == 'Internet Explorer' and $this->agent->version() <= 9) or  ($this->agent->browser() == 'Firefox' and $this->agent->version() <= 24) or ($this->agent->browser() == 'Chrome' and $this->agent->version() <= 23) or ($this->agent->browser() == 'Safari' and $this->agent->version() <= 6) or ($this->agent->browser() == 'Opera' and $this->agent->version() <= 12.1) ){
            redirect('/app/upgrade');
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. All I did was change the 6, to '6' (wrapped in single quotes), and it worked.